# Regex Url Check

Tags: java, regex, apache, mod-rewrite

I am stuck with a simple regex problem. 
What I want to do is to check a URL to see if it contains the word ajax and if it does then match on the URL.

For instance 
given URL localhost/ajax/image/get
should match and return localhost/ajax/image/get

However localhost/image/get
should not match.

I've basic knowledge of regex but havn't been able to get anything working for it.

Any suggestions? I'm sure this is quite a simple case.

I am using this for a mod rewrite Rule

The mod rewrite rule is 
RewriteRule ^.*?\bajax\b.*$ ajax.php?url=$1 [PT,L]

URL requested http://localhost:93/public/ajax/image/

It redirects to the ajax.php file but the url values are not preserved.

I have another rule which is a general one as follows
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [PT,L]

URL requested http://localhost:93/public/imgage/get/

When this redirects to index.php it has /public/image/get/ in the url GET value

Comment: will `/ajax/` always be the root folder for a request like this?

Comment: not always, as long as its part of the url

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the issue, the regex i was looking for is
^(.*ajax.*)$

I had been trying ^(*ajax*)$ but this doesn't make sense.

Thanks for help

Answer (score 1):

Simple regex. You have multiple tags so I am not quite sure what your platform is. If it is java :

```
Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("^.*?\\bajax\\b.*$");
```

In general this should be the regex :

```
   /^.*?\bajax\b.*$/
```

**Explanation :**

```
"^" +       // Assert position at the beginning of the string
"." +       // Match any single character that is not a line break character
   "*?" +      // Between zero and unlimited times, as few times as possible, expanding as needed (lazy)
"\\b" +      // Assert position at a word boundary
"ajax" +    // Match the characters “ajax” literally
"\\b" +      // Assert position at a word boundary
"." +       // Match any single character that is not a line break character
   "*" +       // Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
"$"         // Assert position at the end of the string (or before the line break at the end of the string, if any)
```

Finally I would suggest [this](http://www.regular-expressions.info/) for further reading.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the help, this one of regexs I was trying, I would expect this to work. However using a netbeans plugin to test the regex and an Apache mod_rewrite URL for where I will be placing the rule neither seem to match. I had 4 tags because I must have 4 tags for asking a question. I will post my mod_rewrite rule and the url I hit

Answer (score 0):

What about

```
[a-z/]*ajax[a-z/]*
```

it could use some refinement, so let me know if it needs to be improved.

Comment: i dont think this will match because I don't think it will not match the http:// part. I have tried this and it fails to match

Comment: is the xxxx:// part always going to be there? if so, try [a-z]+://[a-z._/-]*ajax[a-z._/-]*

Answer (score 0):

It should be as simple as:

```
Pattern.matches(regex, str)
```

so

Pattern.matches("ajax", str)

where str is the url string being passed in.

Comment: Hi paul, I'm using it in a mod rewrite, as i was testing the regex in a netbeans plug in and I'm required to put 4 tags on the question I put java as a tag. See above for extra notes

Comment: @Paul this will also match blajaxbla

Comment: @failedDev not if you use "ajax."

Comment: @Paul Well this is the point, you may use blajax. This matches but it shouldn't.

Comment: @failed dev, he changed his question and didn't have blaajaxbla in his orginal question, but there's no full stop after blaaajaxbla so it wouldn't get picked up in this case.